# Dataframe column is a string that contains a country, I want to create a new column with that country

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column which is a string that sometimes contains a country.

I have an array with all possible country names.

I want to return a new column within the dataframe with the country name if contained in the first column otherwise return null value.

The dataframe, I expect:

```py
country = ['Angola', 'Belgium']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['A product for Angola', 'Angola'], ['A product for Belgium', 'Belgium']]), columns=['Product', 'Country'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with regex - join all values by `|` for regex `OR`:

```
country = ['Angola', "Korea (Democratic People's Republic of)"]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['A product for Angola', 'Angola'], 
                            ["A product for Korea (Democratic People's Republic of)",
                             "Korea (Democratic People's Republic of)"],
                            ['A product for new', None]]), columns=['Product', 'Country'])

import re

pat = '|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in country)
df['newCountry'] = df['Product'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
print (df)
                                             Product  \
0                               A product for Angola   
1  A product for Korea (Democratic People's Repub...   
2                                  A product for new   

                                   Country  \
0                                   Angola   
1  Korea (Democratic People's Republic of)   
2                                     None   

                                newCountry  
0                                   Angola  
1  Korea (Democratic People's Republic of)  
2                                      NaN
```

Comment: Nice one, was trying without the boundaries but they are necessary here +1

Comment: @jezrael - thank you for the solution. I omitted to mention countries several strings, ie: United Kingdom or United Arab Emirates. How do we work around that?

Comment: @BrunoGG - It working nice too, check edited answer.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael! Then I do not know why I get the following error: 

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 1

Comment: @jezrael probably because I have such strings "Korea (Democratic People's Republic of)". I can obviously change the string in the list, but is there any way around it.
Thanks for your time and patience :)

Comment: @BrunoGG - need `re.escape`, because `()` are parsed like regex, so raised error. Check edited answer.